# AWS: How to list Snapshots which are created from a particular volume via AWSCLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have  a volume and many snapshots have been created out of it. How to list all the snapshots of that particular volume?

Answer (score 5):

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filter Name=volume-id,Values=vol-xyz
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html for more information.

Comment: I am getting the followoing error. Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in Filters[0]: "volume-id", must be one of: Name, Values

Comment: Syntax:  aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filter "volume-id=vol-xxxxxx"